# Azure portal : can´t create virtual machines of series B

Tags: azure, virtual-machines

I have a new free tier account and I can´t create a virtual machine B1S. I have tried Ubuntu and Microsoft server images and all the regions and always I can only choose series D. I have a friend that do the same thing as me and he can choose B1S.

Answer (score 0):

Send a message to `@AzureSupport` on Twitter. It's free and they are very good about replying quickly.

Comment: Hi,ok thank you very much i will try this way ;)

Answer (score 0):

Azure blog statement on new subscription restrictions:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/update-2-on-microsoft-cloud-services-continuity/

The Azure `Consumption/Services Experience` team has another official statement:

> Sorry for the inconvenience, we are currently prioritizing existing
>   subscriptions over newly-created subscriptions in your region. Since
>   you are an existing customer, you can request that your new
>   subscription(s) be enabled for your preferred region – these are
>   reviewed and approved on a case by case basis. Please create a new
>   support request - select an issue type of 'Service and subscription
>   limits (quotas)", the relevant subscription and resource quota type.

Source: internal statement on the Azure team's SharePoint site.

You can file a request here:
https://aka.ms/azuresupportportal

Thanks!